# error C2664: 'HWND cannot convert argument 2 from 'lpctstr' to 'lpcwstr' Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets 3.0.2 and visual Studio 2015 am much new to wxWidgets.
What is the reason for the given errors some are saying it's because of the order of includes and others are saying because of unicodes. So am expecting a clear answer.

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(38): error C2664: 'HWND CreateDialogParamW(HINSTANCE,LPCWSTR,HWND,DLGPROC,LPARAM)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'
 C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(38): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(69): error C2664: 'HFONT CreateFontW(int,int,int,int,int,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 14 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'
  C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(69): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(95): error C2664: 'HWND CreateWindowExW(DWORD,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,DWORD,int,int,int,int,HWND,HMENU,HINSTANCE,LPVOID)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'
  C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(95): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(111): error C2664: 'HMENU LoadMenuW(HINSTANCE,LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'
  C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(111): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(311): error C2664: 'HICON LoadIconW(HINSTANCE,LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'
  C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(311): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(324): error C2664: 'HBITMAP LoadBitmapW(HINSTANCE,LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPCTSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'
  C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx/msw/winundef.h(324): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pass ASCII string pointers to functions that expect wide string pointers.

Comment: @Michael: Normally why these sorts of error occur, When i googled it's a common error but no clear answer

Comment: If this is code written by you, fix the code so that it uses the proper types. If this is code written by someone else, find a way to either configure the library to use Unicode, or configure your project to compile without Unicode support.

Comment: @leox, can you post the file you are trying to compile? I presume this is the code you wrote.... Also, just to make sure - can you successfully compile 'minimal' sample?

Comment: Unfortunately the code has not been written by me.

Comment: @leox, thats OK. As long as you are not receiving it from the wxWidgets itself, which I seriously doubt... Just drop the code here in the "code" tags.

Comment: Project > Properties > General > "Character set" setting.  You have to pick Unicode, wxWidgets requires it.  That's probably going to now cause errors in your own code.  Use the letter L (like L"text") to create Unicode compatible literals.  Windows has been a Unicode operating system for 23 years already, time to get used to it :)

Comment: Unicode is already enabled in the project so that's not the thing causing error

Comment: This is a bad question because you don't provide the steps necessary to reproduce what you see and nobody else sees it. You need to make a minimal example showing them. Otherwise nobody knows what exactly are you doing.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be compiling your code with the wrong mix of `wxUSE_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol values. It would be best if you showed what exactly are you compiling (the smaller example, the better) and the compiler options you use. In the absence of this information, all I can say is that if you simply set "Character Set" to "Use Unicode" in the "General" page of the project options dialog in the IDE and don't do anything else, everything should compile out of the box without any problems.

Of course, if you had already edited `include/wx/msw/setup.h` file and, for example, changed the value of `wxUSE_UNICODE` there, you need to revert this. I.e. please make sure you use *unmodified* wxWidgets sources.

Comment: If the UNICODE and _UNICODE is enabled in the project then LPCTSTR will be equivalent to LPCWSTR right.? so if i call LoadStringW() in winuser.h it is expecting a LPCWSTR. So is there anyway that i can pass LPCTSTR and which get implicitly converted to LPCWSTR.?

Comment: Also i made no changes to setup.h

Comment: Yes. if `UNICODE` is defined, `wxUSE_UNICODE` is _not_ explicitly defined as 0 and you still get errors due to `LPCTSTR` and `LPCWSTR` being different types, something undefines `UNICODE` in your code. Find it and get rid of it. It's really impossible to say more because you've never shown the code you were compiling!

Comment: Thanks VZ i will looks for it and fix it

Answer (score 3):

As discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-users/pC9mNUMUgtI), that's due to some Windows header being included before Wx ones (unless you really tinkered hard with Unicode, as discussed above). 
Give a check to their order and you should be fine.